# bibtex: how to change the behavior of add.period

Tags: bibtex, bst

I'm making a thesis template for my university. In my school's standard file, all the periods generated by `add.period` should be full width, i.e.

```
[J]. Some Press ->　[J]．Some Press
Full Stop: U+002E -> Fullwidth Full Stop: U+FF0E
```

(mention the difference of the two periods)

What should I do?
Or can I use another function to generate the period? If I use my function, how can I make it follow the rules in *btxhak.pdf*?[image]

Comment: What exactly is a `full width period`?

Comment: @daleif I added the Unicode in my question :)

Comment: Isn't this the same as just using `.\ ` (of course this does not create that unicode char), I just don't really see the point here of a copyable period with space. Note that bibtex problably cannot deal with unicode at all.

Comment: I can't use `.\ ` instead of the fullwidth character, since I'm using a Chinese package `ctex`. Inside this package, there are rules about some characters "can't appear at a line's start" (I don't know how to describe this property) . And fullwidth full stop is inside this set, full stop isn't.